# Merge rows based on range of variable

Tags: python, pandas, merge

```
df1:
 lower_bound_ip_address           upper_bound_ip_address    country
0              16777216.0                16777471          Australia
1              16777472.0                16777727          China
2              16777728.0                16778239          China
3              16778240.0                16779263          Australia
4              16779264.0                16781311          China

df: 
     ip_address
0    7.327584e+08
1    3.503114e+08
2    2.621474e+09
3    3.840542e+09
4    4.155831e+08
5    2.809315e+09
6    3.987484e+09
7    1.692459e+09
8    3.719094e+09
9    3.416747e+08
```

I'm new to python. 
I want to match df['ip_address'] with df1['country']. Certain ip_address range is corresponding to specific country, for example:  729808896-734003199 indicates Japan. How to do that?

I wrote the following code, but there is error.
TypeError: len() of unsized object

```
for x in df['ip_address']:
    if x<=df1['upper_bound_ip_address'] and x>=df1['lower_bound_ip_address']:
        df['country']=df1['country']
```

Comment: post your dataframe as text instead of iages and what is the error

Comment: TypeError: len() of unsized object

Comment: post your dataframe as text instead of images

Answer (score 2):

***`pandas`***
`pd.merge_asof` + `query`

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df.sort_values('ip_address'), df1,
    left_on='ip_address', right_on='lower_bound_ip_address'
).query('ip_address <= upper_bound_ip_address')[['ip_address', 'country']]
```

***`numpy`***
`np.searchsorted`

```
b = df1.values[:, :2].ravel()
c = df1.country.values
ip = df.ip_address.values
srch = b.searchsorted(ip) // 2
mask = (ip >= b[0]) & (ip <= b[-1])
df.loc[mask, 'country'] = c[srch[mask]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is going to be more like this...

```
for x in df['ip_address']:
    for y in df1:
        if x<=y['upper_bound_ip_address'] and x>=y['lower_bound_ip_address']:
            x['country']=y['country']
```

This is assuming df is a list of dictionaries. This will append the country to each dictionary if the number falls into the correct range.

Comment: I ran the code, it gives me an error.                                                     TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Replace "for x in df['ip_address']" with "for x in df"

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(0, len(df)):
    for y in range(0, len(df1)):
        if (df.iloc[x,'ip_address'] <= df1.iloc[y,'upper_bound_ip_address'] and (df.iloc[x,'ip_address'] >= df1.iloc[y,'lower_bound_ip_address']):
            df['country']=df1.iloc[y,'country']
```

what is the difference with @Geoff's answer and this one?